# Running cloudformation template fails when using custom Transform in CodeBuild

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-codebuild

One of my build steps runs a cloudformation template which has a custom transform. The transform is available in us-east-1 which is the same region in which code build is running. This same cloudformation template works when I run it with my local cli. Could you provide how to get this transform working in the code build container.

My local cli is `aws-cli/1.16.223 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.213`

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 

Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 207, in main 
    return command_table[parsed_args.command](remaining, parsed_args) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 348, in __call__ 
    return command_table[parsed_args.operation](remaining, parsed_globals) 

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/awscli/customizations/commands.py", line 187, in __call__ 
    return self._run_main(parsed_args, parsed_globals) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/awscli/customizations/cloudformation/deploy.py", line 295, in _run_main 
    parsed_args.fail_on_empty_changeset) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/awscli/customizations/cloudformation/deploy.py", line 310, in deploy 
    tags=tags 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/awscli/customizations/cloudformation/deployer.py", line 227, in create_and_wait_for_changeset 
    self.wait_for_changeset(result.changeset_id, stack_name) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/awscli/customizations/cloudformation/deployer.py", line 178, in wait_for_changeset 
    .format(ex, status, reason)) 
RuntimeError: Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Failed to execute transform REDACTED::ALKSify 
2019-08-21 17:03:42,717 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255 

Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Failed to execute transform REDACTED::ALKSify
```

Comment: You probably have more details about the failure in the CloudFormation console. If the transform lambda was invoked you could also have more details in CloudWatch.

Comment: @LaurentJalbertSimard There isnt any addional information in CloudFormation or CloudWatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just run into the same issue and could solve it as follows.

You need to add the 2 following permissions to the IAM Role of your CodeBuild project.

1. Allow `"cloudformation:CreateChangeSet"` on the macro resource itself `!Sub ${AWS::AccountId}::ALKSify`
2. Allow `"lambda:InvokeFunction"` on the lambda function that implements the macro.

So it would look like:

```
  BuildProjectRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service: codebuild.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: codebuild
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Sid: lambda
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:<MACRO FUNCTION NAME>"
              - Sid: macro
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet"
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}::<MACRO NAME>"

              .... <Other Permissions>
```

Cheers,
Stan